# how Disable app from network traffic capturing to use my app

Tags: java

I want to disable all applications that want to network traffic capturing for code java

exmple

Please delete the HttpCanary app - to use this app

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because stackoverflow isnt a free coding service that implements vague requirements.

Comment: Hint: this place is for specific questions on programming, not a place where people dump vague requirements hoping that other people do all the heavy lifting for you. So please see the [help] to learn what/how to ask here.

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible. You don't have control over that, since a network traffic capturer can also run on another device (such as a router). For me, a message that requires me to uninstall another app, would be a reason to uninstall *your* application. If you want to prevent that your communication is analyzed, use encryption instead. But even that won't prevent people from using debuggers to analyze your code. Note also that "security trough obscurity" does not work.